# Multiple WebPart zones in Custom Layout Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, 2016

Below screenshot is my custom page layout which will be the landing page for the site. I have designed this page as publishing page, but I would like to add web part page functionality to this page in order to give my users to edit the content of the sections.

It looks like I need to add web part zones to those boxes on the screenshot. What is the best way of doing it?

I have added below code snipped as per MSDN to my page, but it errors with message:

> Literal content "--> MS" is not allowed within a 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone

```
<div data-name="WebPartZone">
<!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<div xmlns:ie="ie">
    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="x0e5f5212505f48a9aac43df13eeae4f9" AllowCustomization="True" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" LockLayout="True" Orientation="Vertical">-->
        <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
           <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
</div>
<!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
```

[image: my dashboard]

Comment: Have you tried Design Manager. You can create these snippets using that and paste it in your layout.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek have you resolved your issue? Please post your answer if you found it.